# Go: allow for keyboard input while tcp listener is running

Tags: go, input, tcp, infinite-loop

I'm writing an application which should both **listen for incoming TCP** connections, but also **send TCP packets** when requested.

I have a simple `Listen` function, which accepts the incoming connections

```
func (a *App) Listen() {
    for {
        conn, err := a.listener.Accept()

        if err != nil {
            // log error
        } else {
            go ProcessConn(conn)
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a Send function which performs the dialing in order to send a TCP packet

```
func (a *App) Send(message []byte, host string, port string) error {

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host+":"+port)

    if err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        defer conn.Close()
    }

    _, err = conn.Write(message)
    return err
}
```

Now, when I start my app using the Start function it runs an infinite loop (for the listening for incoming connections), so from the perspective of the terminal the program 'freezes' and does not react to any keyboard operations (expect the CTRL-C).

```
func (a *App) Start() error {

    defer a.Listen()

    // perform some unrelated operations

    return nil
}
```

However, I would like to improve my app, in such a way, that it can take users (keyboard) input in order to notify my app that it should send a message (I want the users to be able to give the parameters: message and address of the destination.) I was reading about select statement here: https://gobyexample.com/select. and wanted to use it for my app.

This is what I wrote based on the example from the go website:

```
func UserReacted(c2 chan string){
    for {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        c2 <- text
    }
}

func main() {

    a := NewApp()
    a.Start()

    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        UserReacted(c2)
    }()


    for {
        select {
        case msg2 := <-c2:
            a.Send() // with some parameters added later
        default:
        }
    }
    <-finish
}
```

I understand how the example from the go website works, but I don't know how to use select when one of the function, in my example the Listen function, is not returning any value. I will be very grateful for any advice or example how to do it properly.

Comment: What is `a.Run()`, why is it deferred, and is it blocking?

Comment: I don't think a `select` will solve your problem, it sounds like you need concurrency, i.e. goroutines.

Comment: Sorry, instead of Run it should be Listen. Also, it is deferred because Start  performs some other read/write operations which should be finished before Listen is started. And yes, Listen is blocking.

Comment: @Adrian More explanation or an example would be very helpful!

Comment: @Ziva: well if `Listen` is blocking, that means `Start` is blocking, which means you can't execute any of the input code. (while not incorrect, it is also strange to unnecessarily defer part of program logic like that)

Comment: "how to use concurrency" is probably too broad for SO and also incredibly well-covered by the Go tour, Go documentation, and many resources around the internet.

Comment: @Adrian I've read about go concurrency so I know what it is, but I don't know how to use it in such particular case. Maybe it is enough for my case to just have a start function running Listen and UserReacted as two separate go routines?